# Calculate Grade Points and Credits needed to reach a specific GPA

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms, combinations

I'm attempting to come up with a formula that solves the amount of Grade Points and Credits Needed to achieve a certain GPA (On a $4.0$ scale). The formula for GPA is Grade Points / Credits.

As an example, let's say I have obtained $18$ Grade Points from $12$ Credits, this would result in me having a GPA of $1.5$ If my target GPA is $2.0$ by the end of the semester, I would need to obtain $12$ more Grade Points from 3 Credits. By the end of the semester I would have a $2.0$ GPA $(18+12)/(12+3) = 30/15 = 2.0$ GPA.

Now, how could I produce a formula to know how many Grade Points and Credits I would need based on my current Grade Points and Credits to achieve a bare minimum of $2.0$ GPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P$ represent the points you currently have, and $C$ represent the credits taken. As you pointed out, your current GPA would be $\frac{P}{C}$.

Then let $P_s$ represent the points you will earn in the next semester, and $C_s$ be the number of credits you will take next semester. After the semester is over, your GPA would be calculated by $\frac{P+P_s}{C+C_s}$.

Since your desired GPA is $2.0$, we are interested in solving $\frac{P+P_s}{C+C_s}=2$.

I think the most beneficial formula for you will come from isolating $P_s$ in the equation above. That formula is $P_s=2(C+C_s)-P$.

Once you know how many credits you have signed up for, you can plug in all the values on the right hand side to compute the number of points you need to get a $2.0$ GPA. You could also change the $2$ in the formula to a different GPA if you wanted.

Comment: This is exactly, what I was looking for! Thank you, very much!